# How to run separate node server in electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm building an Electron app using React.
I couldn't get the native node module "printer" to work in electron. There were problems while rebuilding native node module. I need the list of printers that are connected to the device in my app. Then print text using specific printer.
So I decided to run an express server separate from electron. Express app needs to have its own node_modules and package.json. And client side will connect the local node server via http request to localhost.

Is it possible to do so? How can I add express app to the dist folder which is created by electron-builder and make it run when electron app is launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a way to way the native printing functionality in electron.
Please follow the below link.
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsgetprinters

Comment: I found an electron-pos-printer module. But can't get it to work in React. https://github.com/fssonca/electron-printer

Comment: I've tried to getPrinters. It works nice. Now I managed to use electron-pos-printer package. But I will definitely try electron's own print function very soon. thank you!

Comment: I had to call electron functions in preload file, then call them in react using window